# How to set a constant to use outside of its scope in a if statement?

Tags: swift, if-statement, scope

I have three global variables:

```
var activeTextField = UITextField() // stores the last textFieldDidBeginEditing
var activeTextView = UITextView() // stores the last textViewDidBeginEditing
var lastTextKindIsTextView = true // indicates if the last text used is a UITextView
```

I would like to count the number of selected characters of the first responder text field or text view. I tryed with this code but it don't work because activeField is out of scope. Is there a way to do this?

```
if lastTextKindIsTextView {
    let activeField = activeTextView
} else {
    let activeField = activeTextField
}

// see the length of the selected string
var strLength = 0

// don't work because activeField is out of scope:
if let textRange = activeField.selectedTextRange { 
    let selectedText = activeField.text(in: textRange)
    strLength = (selectedText?.utf16.count)!
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the variable before the `if - else` expression

```
let activeField : UITextInput
if lastTextKindIsTextView {
    activeField = activeTextView
} else {
    activeField = activeTextField
}
```

or without `if - else`

```
let activeField : UITextInput = lastTextKindIsTextView ? activeTextView : activeTextField
```

Comment: I vadian, activeTextField and activeTextView are variable of two different types.

Comment: Right, but both types conform to `UITextInput`. I updated the answer.